# Creating new objects in Actionscript 2

Tags: flash, object, actionscript-2

I've been trying to create multiple instances of an object in Actionscript2 and have tried many different ways of doing it but keep getting stuck. Basically, when I create a single object, it works fine, but when I try to create 2 or more, only the last one is created. The current state of my script is as follows:

In a separate file, called **allSprites.as**, I have the following:

```
class allSprites
{
    public var spriteName:Object;
    public function moveRight(targetX:Number, theSpeed:Number)
    {
        if (this.spriteName._x <= targetX - theSpeed)
        {
            this.spriteName._x += theSpeed;
            if (_root.stopFrameRepeat == 0)
            {
                _root.gotoAndPlay(_root._currentframe - 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.spriteName._x = targetX;
        }
    }
}
```

and on the timeline (after the sprites bigTomMC and LizMC have been created), I have this:

```
var BigTom:allSprites = new allSprites();
BigTom.spriteName = bigTomMC;

var Liz:allSprites = new allSprites();
Liz.spriteName = LizMC;
```

I can then use commands like `Liz.moveRight(800,5);` to animate the sprites. As I've said, this all works fine when only one object is created, but not at all when more than one is and I have no idea why! Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you adding BigTom and Liz to the stage? Can you paste in the rest of code?

Comment: Yes , you need to show us the part of your code where you're adding them on stage , it seems you have some `depth` assignation mistake

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying - my PC died! Both BigTom and Liz are symbols that are manually added to the timeline (ie dragged from the library and dropped on the stage) before their `new allSprites()` commands are run. There's not any other code that applies to them.

Comment: No takers for this, then?